# How do I separate the RPC client and server so that the server runs on app engine and the client runs on my computer?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, rpc

I'm very new to all this, so please bear with me. I just completed [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC) tutorial on RPC in GWT. In the tutorial, you create a stockwatcher application that displays stock information. The application gets data from a server using RPC. I deployed the project to app engine and it works great.

Now I would like a separate, normal java project that runs on my computer and displays stocks that it retrieves from the app engine server using rpc.  In the stockwatcher tutorial, there is a client and server package. I refactored the client package into a new project to start. I understand that I need to give it the appropriate url, but I'm not sure how to do that.  The StockPriceService has the annotation @RemoteServiceRelativePath("stockPrices") so my first thought was to somehow change that to the correct app engine url.  Is there an annotation that allows me to put in the entire url? If someone could point me in the direction of a tutorial that deals with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

THANK YOU!!! :)

**Edit**

I'm trying to make a client that will run on my computer, another client that will run on my phone, and a simple app engine server that will store some data. After doing the RPC tutorial, using RPCs seemed like a good way for me to send and receive data. I just don't know how to setup the RPC service across multiple projects.

**Edit 2**

I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116870/how-can-i-call-a-gwt-rpc-method-on-a-server-from-a-non-gwt-but-java-gapplicati?rq=1) so I guess what I want to do isn't possible. I guess my new question is, what's the best way to send and receive data between app engine and a non-gwt project?

Answer (score 0):

Pls see the following links 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/appengine
An appengine project will run your machine, you can really deploy it, but you need an account.

Comment: I did the tutorial in getting started and deployed to app engine. If I created a second project, how would I send data to the app engine project?

Comment: If your client is not GWT you can't use GWT-RPC, You can have as many applications as you want, (mobile etc.) Each application will communicate with its servlet. The servlet will communicate with the backend, which is in your case is the Appengine. the browser and the servlets can communicate with GWT-RPC, only if the browser is running a GWT client. Otherwise just HTTP POST your data in JSON format. I hope I that helps.